# Trying Back ground Service is Fetching Data From Sqlite Database Send to Web, Same Time Listview Showing Data From Sqlite Database Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite

Help me how to resolve it,

Every 10 Mins Sync Sqlite database Data to web service using background Service, parallely Listview fetching same Table data from sqlite database.

Whenever Service is getting data from Local Database to web service, Listview not showing data.

also OnClick listview item entire data will show in next page, fetch from local database, its Showing empty page.

After finishing background Service ,its showing Data in Listview and next view page.

Listview page--->On item view Page.

iam Using Cursor adpter for fetching data from Local database to listview.

[this link i have referred](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-populate-listview-from-sqlite.html/%22This%20Link%20I%20Have%20refered%22)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us code you have written, ask specific questions.

Comment: simple Cursor Adpter only I Have Used, Fetching Listview data. Onclick Listview Item Showing Entire  Row in Next Page. That time Back ground Service is Running (Sync Local database to web ),Not  Showing entire row data in next page.

Comment: after service is Running finished, Showing Perfectly Listview,also Onclick Listview Item  Entire Row data In next page.

Comment: Whiskey Tango Foxtrot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear: use Periodic service. I had the same problem i solved like this. In my case this was the code.

**Service Code:**

```
public class PeriodicService  extends Service {
    private static final long TIMEREQ = 10000 * 60;// 10 mints

    public static String LOG = "Log";

    private final Context mContext;

    public UpdateServices(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public UpdateServices() {
        super();
        mContext = UpdateServices.this;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(LOG, "Service started");
        // save in sqlite after 10 mints
        DatabaseManger db = new DatabaseManger(mContext);
        db.open();
        db.insert("anything", "data");
        db.close();

        // upload data to somewhere server
        new CreateNewProduct(this).execute();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, UpdateServices.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                TIMEREQ, pintent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, UpdateServices.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pintent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "service stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You can get helf [**from here**](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)
**Start and stop your service**

Call start service. As according to the life cycle of the service the destroy method is called when the service is stopped. After stopping the service pending intent is not used where the service is delayed for some time according to your choice.

**From an Activity call**

```
   btn_startService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(About.this, UpdateServices.class));
        }
    });

   btn_stopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(About.this, UpdateServices.class));

            }
        });
```

to for list view **refresh your listadapter**.

Comment: Thank you. one doubt after stopping the service it will run again after 10 mins or not

Comment: check my edit answer i solve your issue that what you want... :)
if it work then accept my answer

Comment: i Have given pending intent is every 10 mins , if once service is stopped it will start again automatically or Not

Comment: one pendingintent define in onCreate() and another in onDestory() i have already done. check my edited code...